# Close application from task-bar when a modal dialog is opened

Tags: java, swing, dialog, taskbar

When a modal dialog is opened, is there any way to allow user close a `JFrame` by clicking `Close` on task-bar icon? I see that even if the dialog is orphan or a child of another frame, it still blocks the `Close` action.

Comment: I think that this might be an operating system issue more than a Java issue. Can you close other apps in this way, for instance WordPad, when you have a modal dialog (e.g., the "save" dialog) open?

Comment: Im with Hover. This is an OS limitation, and one that makes some sense. If a dialog was "modal" then you shouldnt be able to close the application without first closing the dialog. (Modal, in this example, sounds like application modality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the native OS you're running on, I don't know of any that do allow you to.

Here is a MSDN listing on it :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx

> A modal dialog box is displayed by a function when the function needs
>   additional data from a user to continue. Because the function depends
>   on the modal dialog box to gather data, the modal dialog box also
>   prevents a user from activating other windows in the application while
>   it remains open.